# Packery - JavaScript: Safari rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, packery

I have a blog size which pulls in blog titles and featured images into blocks.

The blocks are then organised by Packery.js so that they are tiled across the width of the viewport and there are no spaces between each.

This renders fine in all tested browsers except Safari, where it jumbles all of the divs on top of one another.

Have you seen this before? What can you suggest for a possible solution?

Set up is:

```js
// Dependencies: Isotope.js, Packery.js, ImagesLoaded.js

var $content = $('.site-main'),
        $block3x3 = $content.find('.block3x3'),
        $block3x2 = $content.find('.block3x2'),
        $block3x1 = $content.find('.block3x1'),
  $block2x2 = $content.find('.block2x2'),
  $block2x1 = $content.find('.block2x1'),
  $block1x1 = $content.find('.block1x1'),
        itemSelector = '.block',
  stamp = '.stamp',
  $h1widget = $('.h1widget'),
        $instagramwidget = $('#text-2'),
        $twitterwidget = $('.widget_fetch_tweets_widget_by_id'),
  twitteractualheight = $twitterwidget.height(),
        columnWidth = '.grid-sizer',
        gutter = '.gutter-sizer',
  rowHeight2 = $('.grid-sizer').width(),
        columnWidth2 = $('.grid-sizer').width(),
        gutter2 = $('.gutter-sizer').width();
  

  $h1widget.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : columnWidth2,
   'left': '',
            'top' : 0
        });
  $instagramwidget.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : columnWidth2,
   'right': '',
            'top' : columnWidth2 + gutter2
        });
  
  if (twitteractualheight <= (columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2)){ 
  $twitterwidget.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : '',
   'minHeight': columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2,
   'right': '',
            'top' : columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
        });
  } else {
   $twitterwidget.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : '',
   'minHeight': columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2,
   'right': '',
            'top' : columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
        });
  }

 function initPackery() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 600){
   $content.imagesLoaded( function() {
   $content.isotope({
    layoutMode: 'packery',
    packery: {
     gutter: gutter,
     columnWidth: columnWidth,
     transitionDuration: 0,
    },
    stamp: stamp,
    itemSelector: itemSelector,
    percentPosition: true,
   });
  });
  } else {
  $content.imagesLoaded( function() {
   $content.isotope({
    layoutMode: 'packery',
    packery: {
     gutter: gutter,
     columnWidth: columnWidth,
     transitionDuration: 0,
     isAnimated: false
    },
    stamp: stamp,
    itemSelector: itemSelector,
    percentPosition: true,
   });
  });
  }
 }

    function resizeAll() {
    $block3x3 = $content.find('.block3x3');
        $block3x2 = $content.find('.block3x2');
        $block3x1 = $content.find('.block3x1');
  $block2x2 = $content.find('.block2x2');
  $block2x1 = $content.find('.block2x1');
  $block1x1 = $content.find('.block1x1');
  rowHeight2 = $('.grid-sizer').width();
        columnWidth2 = $('.grid-sizer').width();
        gutter2 = $('.gutter-sizer').width();
  $h1widget = $('.h1widget');
        $instagramwidget = $('#text-2');
        $twitterwidget = $('.widget_fetch_tweets_widget_by_id');
  
  if ($(window).width() <= 650){
   stamp = null;
  } else {
   stamp = '.stamp';
  }
  
  
        if ($(window).width() <= 550){
   
   
   $block3x3.css({
    'width' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
    'height' : ''
   });
   
   $block3x2.css({
    'width' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
    'height' : ''
   });
   
   $block3x1.css({
    'width' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
    'height' : ''
   });
   
   
   
  } else {
    $block3x3.css({
    'width' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2 + gutter2,
    'height' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2 + gutter2,
   });
   
   $block3x2.css({
    'width' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2 + gutter2,
    'height' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
   });
   
   $block3x1.css({
    'width' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2 + gutter2,
    'height' : columnWidth2
   });

  }
  
        $block2x2.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
            'height' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
        });
  $block2x1.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
            'height' : columnWidth2
        });
  $block1x1.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : columnWidth2
        });  
  $h1widget.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : columnWidth2,
   'left': '',
            'top' : 0
        });
  $instagramwidget.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : columnWidth2,
   'right': '',
            'top' : columnWidth2 + gutter2
        });
  if (twitteractualheight <= (columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2)){ 
  $twitterwidget.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : '',
   'minHeight': columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2,
   'right': '',
            'top' : columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
        });
  } else {
   $twitterwidget.css({
            'width' : columnWidth2,
            'height' : '',
   'minHeight': columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2,
   'right': '',
            'top' : columnWidth2 + gutter2 + columnWidth2 + gutter2,
        });
  }
  
  
    }

    function initInfinite() {
        $('.gridwrapper').infinitescroll({
   loadingImg: "ajax-loader",
            nextSelector: ".next-posts a",
            navSelector: ".navigation",
            itemSelector: ".packeryblock",
            appendCallback: true,
   bufferPx: 100
        }, function(appended) {
             resizeAll();            
   $('.gridwrapper').isotope('stamp', $(stamp));
            $('.gridwrapper').isotope('appended', appended);
            initPackery();
        });
    }

    // End Functions //

    // Actions

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
   resizeAll();
            initPackery();
    });

    $(window).load(function(){
        initInfinite();
  resizeAll();
   initPackery();
    });
});

// Force window resize on document load so that content renders perfectly on Safari -- Ben R.

Outlayer.prototype._getMeasurement = function( measurement, size ) {
    var option = this.options[ measurement ];
    var elem;
    if ( !option ) { // default to 0
       this[ measurement ] = 0;
    } else {
    if ( typeof option === 'function') { //accept a function, apologies for the hack style
       this[ measurement ] = option.call(this, null);
    } else { // use option as an element
       if ( typeof option === 'string' ) {
        elem = this.element.querySelector( option );
       } else if ( isElement( option ) ) {
            elem = option;
       } // use size of element, if element
        this[ measurement ] = elem ? getSize( elem )[ size ] : option;
        } //eo option === function
      } //eo option?
}; //eo _getMeasurement

var config = {
   containerStyle: null, //let us worry about the container
   columnWidth: packery.columnWidth, //bind a function to the columnWidth instead of a fixed selector
   gutter: 0 //get crazy and pack them in tight
};
Packery.columnWidth = function() {
   var width = $('home-content').innerWidth(); //how wide is the container for the layout to pack into
   var columns = packery.columns; //how many columns are there for our layouts
   return (width / columns); //send back the current value dynamically
};
```

```css
.block-title {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 20px;
}
.gutter-sizer {
 width:2%;
}
.grid-sizer {
 width:15%;
}
@media (min-width: 500px){
 .gutter-sizer {
  width:4%;
 }
 .grid-sizer {
  width:48%;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home-entry-content" class="entry-contentjs-isotope"
  data-isotope-options='{ "itemSelector": ".block", "layoutMode": "fitRows" }'>
  <article class="block block3x2">
 <a class="block-wrapper" href="page-url">
   <img width="588" height="384" src="image-source.jpg" class="attachment-block3x2" alt="image alt" />
      <span class="block-title yellow_title">Title</span>
     </a>
    </article>
```

Has anyone successfully overcome this rendering issue? I have tried a few solutions including:

https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/134

https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/44

The strangest thing is that when you manually resize the viewport, the behaviour is what I would expect, with all the items packed and stacked.

Would be grateful in finding any workaround so the site looks reasonable in Safari ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Aha I got it!

Actually what I thought was a JavaScript problem turned out to be a weird Safari rendering issue.

To overcome it I used some Safari-specific CSS hacks to specify the size of my containers, like so:

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { @media {
.block {
    display: inline;
}
.block-title {
    width:370px;
}
.block3x3 {
    width: 588px;
    height: 588px;
}
.block3x2 {
    width: 588px;
    height: 384px;
}
.block3x1 {
    width: 588px;
    height: 180px;
}
.block2x2 {
    width: 384px;
    height: 384px;
}
.block2x1 {
    width: 384px;
    height: 180px;
}
.block1x1 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

This enabled Safari to know the size of the containers independently of the images contained within them.

I think.

If someone can shed light on why this happened I'd love to know more about it.